# Is it possible to convert a file other than text files to binary code?

Tags: binary

Is it possible to convert a file other than text files to binary code? and binary code to a file?...
If so, Is there any softwares available to do that?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to find an new and effective method for file compression.
Is it possible to see the binary code of a file (mp3 or other files)?

Comment: open up the file with a hex editor.